# Dell PowerEdge 2900: raid/Linux conversion logistics

Tags: linux, raid, dell, dell-poweredge

I've got a Dell PowerEdge 2900 (currently running windows) that I want to convert into a Linux server.  But, it's got a hardware RAID controller and I want to be sure I don't destroy the configuration utility.  When it boots, I can currently (when prompted) hit CTRL-R and it launches a raid config utility:

```
PERC 5/i Integrated BIOS Configuration Utility 1.02-0007
```

Where is this utility located (Disk vs BIOS)?  If it's on disk, what's the best way to keep that functionality available post-linux install?

Comment: Does this RAID card have battery backup?  If not, you're better using software RAID...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pre-boot RAID BIOS is embedded into the RAID card. It's completely OS-independent.

Comment: Great; thanks for the swift response.  It sounds almost silly to ask that question since it says "BIOS" in the name, but I seem to remember being bitten once by a raid config utility living on the disk once, and once it's gone, it'd be painful to get back.

Comment: @Gus the RAID-controller needs to map into BIOS so you can boot from a raid-device. Apart from that the configuration is stored in NVRAM of the controller AND in every disk.